# Building widget with data from firebase in flutter returning empty widget

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code i've tried but running it returns an empty widget every time. It seems that the list is emptied at the end of the then() call.

```
final database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
final reviews = database.child("books/12345/reviews");

    Widget getReviewCards(DatabaseReference reviews) {
        List<Widget> reviewList = <Widget>[];
    
        reviews.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          final data = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);
          data.forEach((key, value) { 
             reviewList.add(new ReviewCard(stars: 2, reviewText: value.toString(), username: key));
          });
    
        });
        return Column(children: reviewList);
      }
```

Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Data is loaded from Firebase (and most modern cloud APIs) asynchronously, which leads to your code not executing in the order you expect. Adding some logging makes this easiest to see:

```
print('Before loading data');
reviews.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  print('Loaded data');
});
print('After loading data');
```

If you run this code, you will get:

> Before loading data
>
> After loading data
>
> Loaded data

This is probably not what you expected, but it does perfectly explain why your widget is empty: none of the `reviewList.add(...)` calls have happened yet by the time you return the widget.

---

Instead of returning a `Widget` you will have to return a `Future<Widget>`, which is the promise to return a widget in the future:

```
Future<Widget> getReviewCards(DatabaseReference reviews) { //  Change return type
  return reviews.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) { //  Add return
    final data = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);
    List<Widget> reviewList = <Widget>[];

    data.forEach((key, value) { 
       reviewList.add(new ReviewCard(stars: 2, reviewText: value.toString(), username: key));
    });
    return Column(children: reviewList); //  Moved up    
  });
}
```

---

You can also use Dart's `async` and `await` keywords to make the above a bit more familiar:

```
Future<Widget> getReviewCards(DatabaseReference reviews) async {
  DataSnapshot snapshot = await reviews.once();
  final data = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(snapshot.value);
  List<Widget> reviewList = <Widget>[];

  data.forEach((key, value) { 
     reviewList.add(new ReviewCard(stars: 2, reviewText: value.toString(), username: key));
  });
  return Column(children: reviewList);
}
```

---

If you want to display the widget inside your UI, you'll want to wrap it in a `FutureBuilder`.

---

Also see:

- [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)